# Plugin, compilation unit

Tags: java, xml, plugins, menu, eclipse-plugin

I'm making a plugin, and I want a popup menu to appear only if a .java file that contains a class is selected. My problem is when I select a class within a .java file (IType) the menu also appears. I want it only to appear when a .java file is selected (CompilationUnit).

Example:

[image: example].

My xml code:

```xml
<menuContribution
    allPopups="true"
    locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
         <menu
               id="org.plugin.generate_test.handlers.menus.popupTestMenu2"
               label="Generate"
               mnemonic="P2">
            <command
                  commandId="org.plugin.generate_test.handlers.commands.generateCommand"
                  id="org.plugin.generate_test.handlers.menus.generateCommand"
                  mnemonic="PC2"
                  style="push">
               <visibleWhen
                     checkEnabled="false">
                  <with
                        variable="activeMenuSelection">
                     <iterate
                           ifEmpty="false">
                        <adapt
                              type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                           <test
                                 property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
                                 value="java">
                           </test>
                        </adapt>
                     </iterate>
                  </with>
               </visibleWhen>
            </command>
         </menu>
</menuContribution>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your `<adapt` with a test fo `ICompilationUnit`:

```
<instanceof value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit"/>
```